# Android <device-admin> Error with "Element device-admin doesn't have required attribute android:layout_width"

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow this URL: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html
to learn Android. But I meet some problem:
In my activity_main.xml, the code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
        <disable-keyguard-features />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

But it has a error:
Element device-admin doesn't have required attribute android:layout_width
Element device-admin doesn't have required attribute android:layout_height

I was trying to search some way to solve that, but didn't work.
Thank you for you guys helping!

Comment: This file should not be in the `res/layout-xxxx` folder. Add a new file called (eg.) `dev_admin.xml` and place it in `res/xml` folder. Create this folder if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That XML does not go into a layout resource file. That XML goes in a file in the `res/xml/` directory of your project. In the documentation that you linked to, it would go in `res/xml/device_admin_sample.xml`.

[This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin) contains a couple of sample apps that use the device admin APIs. You will see their device admin metadata in their respective `res/xml/` directories.